# Modifying msys privileges on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, msys

How do I run a `cmd.exe` command in `msys` as a superuser? I am the only user on my laptop and have full administrative privileges once I login.  I assumed I did when I fired up an `msys` shell, but running:

```
cmd //c 'mklink link.txt file.txt'
```

returns that I do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation.

Comment: open a command promopt and esclate the process by using "run as administrator" this only works if the user your using is an Administrator otherwise you have to supply the Administrator's username and password.

Comment: Beautiful. What I did was modify the properties of my msys shortcut to "run as administrator" and that worked perfectly. Thanks for the hint, Ramhound!

Comment: Administrator rights are not required to create hard links. If that's what you were trying to do, the actual syntax would be `cmd /c mklink /h "hard link" "the target file"`

Comment: Yes, and31415 is correct. I was after symbolic links. Though, my shell required the command to be: `cmd //c mklink //h hard_link target_file` to escape the forward slash side effects on the msys bash shell.

Comment: The reason you were getting the not-enough-privileges error is that if you omit the `/h` switch you're creating a *symbolic link*, something which was first introduced in Windows Vista along with the `mklink` command. Per default system settings, you need administrator rights in order to create symbolic links.

Answer (score 1):

## Creating hard links

When using the `mlink` built-in command to create [hard links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you need to use the `/h` switch. If you omit it, the command will create a symbolic link instead.

[Symbolic links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) were first introduced in Windows Vista along with the `mklink` command. Unlike hard links, you *do* need administrator rights in order to create symbolic links, per default system settings. And that's the very reason you were getting the not-enough-privileges error.

Simply put, this is the command syntax you need to use:

```
cmd //c mklink //h hard_link target_file
```

### Further reading

- [Hard link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link)
- [Command-Line Reference](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754340.aspx)